# Can't listen on multiple sockets when using BINDTODEVICE?

Tags: sockets, unix, udp, recvfrom

I have two network links to the Internet, and I have two default routes set up:

```
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         gateway0        0.0.0.0         UG    0      0      eth0
default         gateway1        0.0.0.0         UG    0      0      eth1
...
```

I created two sockets with BINDTODEVICE, so that I can send data out either eth0 or eth1. I am also trying to listen on both sockets using `recvfrom` (UDP data only), but I can only successfully read data from whichever interface is listed first in the routes. `eth0` works, for example, but I get nothing from the socket bound to `eth1`.

Running wireshark on either interface shows data coming in successfully - that is, I can see data being sent from the Internet to either eth0's or eth1's IP in Wireshark (so NAT is not a problem with either), but my program just blocks on `recvfrom` without getting any data.

I have tried using `bind` on the sockets to make them listen on their respective interface's IP, and also tried not using bind to have them listen on 0.0.0.0 (each on a different port), but I still have the same problem.

How can I make sure both sockets get the data they're supposed to?

Edit: sample code:

```
int createDeviceBoundUDPSocket(uint32_t sip, uint16_t sport, const char* bind_dev) {
    printf("bind_dev = %s", bind_dev);
   int s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);   
   int result;
   struct sockaddr_in my_ip_addr;

   if (s < 0) {
      perror("socket");
      return s;
   }

   memset(&my_ip_addr, 0, sizeof(my_ip_addr));

   my_ip_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
   my_ip_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(sip);
   my_ip_addr.sin_port = htons(sport);

   // commenting this section out doesn't seem to make a difference
   // listening on 0.0.0.0 or the interface's IP both have the same problem
   result = bind(s, (struct sockaddr*)(&my_ip_addr), sizeof(my_ip_addr));
   if (result < 0) {
      perror("Error in bind");
      return result;
   }

   if (bind_dev) {
      // Bind to specific device.
      if (setsockopt(s, SOL_SOCKET, SO_BINDTODEVICE,
                     bind_dev, strlen(bind_dev) + 1)) {
         perror("Error binding to device");
         return -1;
      }
   }

   return s;
}
```

Comment: Please show your actual code. You are likely not setting up the bindings correctly.

Comment: Bindings work for sending data out and, for one interface, work for receiving data. So I don't currently suspect that part.

Comment: Don't mix `bind()` and `SO_BINDTODEVICE`.  Use one or the other.  Typically, you should use `bind()`.

Comment: Tried it with both - wrote that above...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution, as hinted by [the Linux Advanced Routing and Traffic Control](http://www.lartc.org/howto/lartc.loadshare.html) guide, is to turn off reverse path filtering. Not sure which of the three interfaces needed to have it turned off, but doing

```
echo 0 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/all/rp_filter
```

made it work.